# How to capture the output of a previous action in power automate

Tags: power-automate

I want to capture the output of an action in a variable, in Power Automate. I am using `body('action name')`, but getting an error:

> Flow save failed with code 'InvalidTemplate' and message 'The template validation failed: 'The action(s) 'Create record' referenced by 'inputs' in action  are not defined in the template.'.'.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://manueltgomes.com/microsoft/powerautomate/power-automate-add-attachment-to-e-mail-dynamically/), you can try something like

```
outputs('action_name')?['body']
```

When referring to action name, it is important to **replace white spaces with underlines**. Thus, action named "FILES TO SEND" will be referred to as outputs('*FILES_TO_SEND*')?['body']

Answer (score 0):

Try with the expression `outputs('action_name')`

Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#outputs